# How to find the list in Python?

Tags: python, list, split, element

I have a list of list in Python:

```
list_all = [['orange', 'the dress', '5643,43245,5434,22344,34533'],
            ['pink', 'cars', '12322,4455,533,2344,24324,64466,543342'],
            ['dark pink' 'doll', '12422,4533,6446,35563'],
            ['blue', 'car', '43356,53352,546'],
            ['sky blue', 'dress', '63463,3635432,354644,6544,6444,644,74245']]
```

I want to return top 3 lists which have the highest count of numbers in the last part. Like this:

```
result = [['orange', 'the dress', '5643,43245,5434,22344,34533'],
         ['pink', 'cars', '12322,4455,533,2344,24324,64466,543342'],
         ['sky blue', 'dress', '63463,3635432,354644,6544,6444,644,74245']]
```

I just cannot find the logic to do this. I have tried a lot, but just got stuck with one line of code:

```
for each in list_all:
    if len(each[-1].split(','))
```

Please help me to solve this. I am new to Python and learning it. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is your definition of `highest length`? It's not clear here.  Notice your numbers are `string` in the code?!

Comment: You can use `sorted` function 

`print(sorted(list_all, key=lambda e: len(e[-1])))`

Comment: What do you mean by highest count of numbers? Why does your result has 3 lists in it?

Comment: I want to find the top 3. Thats why.

Comment: You say *the top 3*. I don't understand why `'5643,43245,5434,22344,34533'` ranks higher than `'12322,4455,533,2344,24324,64466,543342'`. If you're going on the length of the list of numbers, then the 1st has 5 numbers and the second has 7. Why is 5 higher than 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted` function

```
print(sorted(list_all, key=lambda e: len(e[-1].split(',')), reverse=True)[:3])
```

Output:

```
[
['pink', 'cars', '12322,4455,533,2344,24324,64466,543342'], 
['sky blue', 'dress','63463,3635432,354644,6544,6444,644,74245'], 
['orange', 'the dress', '5643,43245,5434,22344,34533']
]
```

The `sorted()` function sorts the elements of a given iterable in a specific order (ascending or descending) and returns it as a list.

More info on [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: @new_user If it works, would you explain why it doesn't produce the output you specified in your question? Your question says *orange, the dress* should come first, but in the output from this code, *blue, car* comes first.

Comment: @BoarGules Actually I was looking for top 3, no matter which output comes first.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a handy one-liner:

```
print(sorted(all_list, key=lambda l: len(l[-1].split(',')))[:-3])
```

Comment: Does the `output` match asker's `expected` output?  Find they're different?

Comment: @DanielHao Yes, because I was looking for top 3, no matter which output comes first.

Comment: No need for reverse if you slice [-3:]